# Rebuild PHP's extract() or how to pass variables to outer scope

Tags: php, design-patterns, scope

I wonder if there is a way to pass variables "one scope level up" in PHP (not to the global scope), just like extract() does. I know I can do this:

```
function inner()
{
    $foo = [
        'bar' => 11,
        'baz' => 22
    ];
    return $foo;
}

function outer()
{
    extract(inner());
    echo $bar;
}

outer(); // 11
```

But is there a pattern where I can omit the extract() call in function outer(), but still access $bar? I ask this just for curiosity.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to. What is wrong with accessing `bar` as an array member?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that, I am just curious if it is possible to rebuild extract's behaviour, to get more understanding about the language

Comment: Array dereferencing? `echo inner()['bar'];`